# Would like to have the value of two or more tag name but have the same timespan, make it in to one query.

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is the values that I want out but wondering if I can do it in one query and also put it in to a temporary table that allready has a lot of information.
I could create a another table and put 4Tot , 16Tot,TotE, and then use that table to transfer to the other table, how do I fix this?
Thanks!

```
4Tot = (select ROUND(b.value-a.value,1) from history a, history b where a.name='TAGG1' 
and b.name=a.name and a.ts between st and (st+00:01) and b.ts between en and (en+00:01)); 

16Tot = (select ROUND(b.value-a.value,1) from history a, history b 
where a.name='TAGG2' and b.name=a.name 
and a.ts between st and (st+00:01) and b.ts between en and (en+00:01)); 

TotE = (select ROUND(b.value-a.value,1) from history a, history b where         
a.name='Tagg3' and b.name=a.name 
and a.ts between st and (st+00:01) and b.ts between en and (en+00:01));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select sum(case a.name when 'TAGG1' then ROUND(b.value-a.value,1) else 0 end) as 4Tot,
       sum(case a.name when 'TAGG2' then ROUND(b.value-a.value,1) else 0 end) as 16Tot,
       sum(case a.name when 'TAGG3' then ROUND(b.value-a.value,1) else 0 end) as TotE
  from history a, history b
 where b.name=a.name
   and a.ts between st and (st+00:01) 
   and b.ts between en and (en+00:01)
```

As per your other problem on the comments, to use this query to store in a table you just need the insert statement with this query like this:

Of course, I'm considering that your other table has just this 3 columns.

```
insert into SomeNewTable ( col1, col2, col3 ) 
select sum(case a.name when 'TAGG1' then ROUND(b.value-a.value,1) else 0 end) as 4Tot,
       sum(case a.name when 'TAGG2' then ROUND(b.value-a.value,1) else 0 end) as 16Tot,
       sum(case a.name when 'TAGG3' then ROUND(b.value-a.value,1) else 0 end) as TotE
  from history a, history b
 where b.name=a.name
   and a.ts between st and (st+00:01) 
   and b.ts between en and (en+00:01)
```

Comment: Think this could work but how to take the value of 'TAGG1' in to my table?

Comment: declare local temporary tabel modul.t("4Tot"double, "16Tot" double,"TotE" double)
insert into module.t ?????????

Comment: I'm not sure if I undestand you. Could you put a desired result on your question. I think it would be easier to understand and give you a proper answer.

Comment: You mean the 'TAGGn' is dynamic?

Comment: So how could I take that result it return and store it in a table?

Comment: Ok, will try to expalin a bit better.
The one query that you wrote how could I store that in a table?

Comment: And also when I have stored it in that table and would take the information in that table and give it to another table.

Comment: See my update if fit to you. To do the 'transpose' from the new table to other table just repeat the insert select statement for the other table.

Comment: Hey Jorge, when I got this working it takes longer time to execute this query then to have several of query asking one varable at a time, why is this?

Comment: Well, it depends on the number of rows that you are working with. If I undertand you right (hope I did), You read theese data from this table (history) then you insert in another table (lets call 2table) and from that 2table you insert in another table is that right?